# My footer is stuck in the middle of the page

Tags: css, footer

I'm having an issue where the footer of my page has now moved up and is stuck with in the picture. This problem didn't use to occur and I'm unsure as to how to fix it.

When entering the website : https://gyazo.com/bcd6fe2f9514e761035deee64d820e22
After scrolling down : https://gyazo.com/cb9b9917d7d1730484c18a093b2a5f12

Here is the part of the code for index.php

```css
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body,

.cover {
    height: 100%;
}

.cover {
    background: url('img/main.jpeg') top left no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px #000;
}

.cover-text {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.cover-text h1 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 70px;
    letter-spacing: -3px;
}

nav.navbar-inverse {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border: none;
}

.the-quote {
    background: #222;
}

blockquote1 {
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: white;
}

blockquote1 cite {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #888;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

section {
    padding: 100px;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0 0 60px;
}

h2 + p {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -60px;
}

#team {
    background: url('img/fan.jpg') top left no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

#reviews p {
    color: black;
}
#reviews h4 {
    font-weight: 600;
}

#reviews {
    text-align: center
}

#contact-us {
    background: url('img/straighten.jpg') left no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
}
footer {
    background: #222;
    color: black;
    text-align: white;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
    position:absolute; 
    bottom: 0; 
    width: 100%;

}

footer a {
    color: hotpink;
}

@media only screen and ( max-width : 568px ) {
    .cover h1 {
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    section {
        padding: 20px;
    }

}

.login-cover {
    background: #333;
    background-size: auto;
    padding-top: 300px;
    min-height: 93.8vh;
    min-width: 100vw;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Modern Haircut Designs</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Stuff -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Coursework Style that's seperate -->
    <link href="coursework_style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
        #My navigation bar code
    </nav>

    <div class="cover" id="top">
        <div class="cover-text">
            <h1>Professional Haircut Service at its finest</h1>
            <p class="lead">It's your haircut so why not choose the exact date, time and barber of your preference.</p>
            <a href="coursework_register.php" role="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Sign up by clicking right here!</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <section class="the-quote">
        # Quote 
    </section>

    <section id="services">
        #List of the services we offer
    </section>

    <section id="team">
        # Team members
    </section>

    <section id="reviews">
       #Reviews
    </section>

    <section id="contact-us">
       #Contact-Us information
    </section>

    <!-- jQuery for javascript stuff-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap javascript code / might remove tho -->
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

<footer>
    crafted with &hearts; in Bangladesh by <a href="#Random Link">Roman Ryan Karim</a>
</footer>
</html>
```

Before this error persisted, the footer used to appear underneath the contact-us section however it now appears the instance you go to the website and is stuck there. Can someone help? I don't mind sharing more of the code if you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove your position absolute, of your footer

Comment: I'm not sure is the best way to solve your problem, but there's not much code to investigate, it's the only thing a can do for help you